# loadxml returns false: what could be the reason for it?

Tags: php, xml, domdocument

I need to parse the XML string. When I pass the string to `pXML` as `$this->loadXML($this->xmlString)` in the following class, it returns `false`. What could be the reason for this?

```
class MXML extends DOMDocument {

        private $version,$encodingType,$rootNode,$videoParam,$encodingFormat,$audioParam,$xmlString;

        /**
         * Initilizes the DOM with version number and encoding
         * @param  $version
         * @param  $encoding
         */
        public function __construct($version,$encoding) {
            parent::__construct($version,$encoding);
            $this->formatOutput = true; // Nicely formats output with indentation and extra space.
        }

        public function pXML($xml) {
            $this->loadXML($this->xmlString); // returns FALSE
            $parameters = $this->getElementsByTagName("Parameter");
            $advanced = $this->getElementsByTagName("Advanced");
            $preprocessing = $this->getElementsByTagName("Preprocessing");
        }

        //..  write xml functions
};
```

Here is how I call `pXML`:

```
$xml = new MXML();
$xml->pXML($result['XMLSettings']);
```

*XML*:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<Cutkompress-Parameters>
  <Video-Params>
    <EncodingFormat-MPEG-4Part2>
      <Parameter>
        <IQuant>7</IQuant>
        <PQuant>7</PQuant>
        <FramesToSkip>7</FramesToSkip>
        <PBetweenI>7</PBetweenI>
        <FrameRate>7</FrameRate>
        <SearchWindow>7</SearchWindow>
      </Parameter>
      <Advanced>
        <QuantType>7</QuantType>
        <QPel>ON</QPel>
        <MV>ON</MV>
        <SceneChange>Detect Medium Change</SceneChange>
        <VOL_Control_Parameters>ON</VOL_Control_Parameters>
      </Advanced>
      <Preprocessing>
        <NoiseReduction>Detect Medium Change</NoiseReduction>
        <SharpnessLevel>7</SharpnessLevel>
      </Preprocessing>
    </EncodingFormat-MPEG-4Part2>
  </Video-Params>
</Cutkompress-Parameters>
```

Comment: Your XML is probably broken, is it small enough to share?

Comment: @hoppa I have shared the xml.

Comment: Could you please add the method `$this->loadXML` to your question? Is `$this->xmlString` a valid xml string?

Comment: @PaulCrovella I'm sorry! I didn't see that you class inherits from DOMDocument :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not parsing the string passed in to pXML, you're attempting to load `$this->xmlString` which isn't set anywhere. You probably intended `$this->loadXML($xml)`.

What you've got should be giving you a warning, by the way. If it isn't take a look at: [How to get useful error messages in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/845021/how-to-get-useful-error-messages-in-php)